# moving a build product into a different directory with scons

Tags: scons

Consider the following snippet

```
env = Environment()
env.PDF(target="personal_statement.pdf", source="personal_statement.tex")
env.Command("documents/personal_statement.pdf", "personal_statement.pdf", Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))
```

If I set `target` in `env.PDF` to "documents/personal_statement.pdf", the LaTeX compilation happens in "documents/personal_statement.pdf". I want only the final output, namely "personal_statement.pdf" to be present in "documents/personal_statement.pdf". 
Currently I am doing this in two steps. Step 1: compile the file, Step 2: move the resulting PDF to another directory.
Is there some way of accomplishing this in one step instead of using two steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation of doing this in two steps is more related to pdflatex rather than SCons. pdflatex has the `-output-directory` option, but it will either write everything (including all of the temporary files) to that directory.

While your example snippet may work, I believe the more typical approach is to use the Install builder.

```
env = DefaultEnvironment()
dst = env.PDF("personal_statement.tex")
inst = env.Install("documents",dst)
Default(inst)
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. By the time you replied, I had stopped working on this. Your approach is certainly more elegant than what I was doing. Thanks.